# Accidentally disabled the administrator account on IPA server

Tags: ldap, freeipa

I'm running ipa-server on Centos 6.  I was going through the users disabling accounts and accidentally disabled the "administrator" account.  Now I have no access to do anything.  Is there any way to restore access to this account?  Or to prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Find out the exact DN of the administrator user:

```
$ ipa user-show admin --all --raw | grep dn
```

... and use *cn=Directory Manager* with password entered during FreeIPA installation (you still remember it, do you?) and enable the account:

```
$ ldapmodify -h ipa.server.fqdn -D "cn=Directory Manager" -ZZ -x -W
dn: uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: nsaccountlock
nsaccountlock: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Log in with a different account and re-enable it, if you have such an account (you should, in all but the smallest deployments).

As of FreeIPA 3.0, which is included in EL 6.4, [it is no longer possible to disable the last administrator account](https://fedorahosted.org/freeipa/ticket/2979).